# oracle 12c r2 give selections permissions to user

Tags: database, oracle, ubuntu

I'm trying to give select permission to "read" user but when I enter with the user I can not do anything.
it gives me the following failure:

```
SQL> desc table
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object enfermeria does not exist
```

to give the permissions I have done this:

```
CREATE USER books_admin IDENTIFIED BY MyPassword;

GRANT CONNECT TO books_admin;
GRANT CONNECT, RESOURCE, DBA TO books_admin;
GRANT CREATE SESSION GRANT ANY PRIVILEGE TO books_admin;
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO books_admin;
GRANT
  SELECT,
ON
  schema.books
TO
  books_admin;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Boy*, you granted whole lot of things to that user, vast majority of the privileges are unnecessary, some of them being even *dangerous* (you shouldn't really grant DBA like that). Also, you should try to post what you really did, and not *make up* stuff (you are trying to describe *table*, while Oracle responded that *enfermeria* doesn't exist)?

Here's a suggestion you might, or might not accept.

I'm going to connect to my XE database as a privileged user (SYS in this case; if there's another one you use for administration purposes, use it) in order to create the *read user*.

```
C:\>sqlplus sys@xe as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Uto Lis 23 21:32:36 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> create user read_user identified by ru
  2  default tablespace users
  3  temporary tablespace temp
  4  quota unlimited on users;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to read_user;

Grant succeeded.
```

Notice what I granted to read_user: create session only. So far, it is the only privilege it needs. If it turns out that it needs something else, grant it, but refrain from granting roles like *connect, resource, dba* - that's not *in the fashion* any more.

Now, connecting as user who owns a table I'd like to let read_user to select from.

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger@xe
Connected.
SQL> grant select on dept to read_user;

Grant succeeded.
```

Finally, connect as read_user and check what it sees:

```
SQL> connect read_user/ru@xe
Connected.
SQL> desc dept
ERROR:
ORA-04043: object dept does not exist
```

Ah! The same error you got! This is because read_user doesn't have DEPT table available - it doesn't exist in his schema, there's no public synonym for it, so - he should precede table name with table's owner name (and that's Scott):

```
SQL> desc scott.dept
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 DEPTNO                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(2)
 DNAME                                              VARCHAR2(14)
 LOC                                                VARCHAR2(13)

SQL> select * from scott.dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

Much better, don't you think?

In order not to specify owner's name, create a synonym to that table (still connected as the read_user):

```
SQL> create synonym dept for scott.dept;
create synonym dept for scott.dept
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Oops! Can't do that, I don't have that privilege. So - back to SYS, grant read_user a privilege so that he could create synonyms, back to read_user again and repeat the statement:

```
SQL> connect sys@xe as sysdba
Enter password:
Connected.
SQL> grant create synonym to read_user;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> connect read_user/ru@xe
Connected.
SQL> create synonym dept for scott.dept;

Synonym created.

SQL> select * from dept;

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON

SQL>
```

I'd suggest you to read what I've written and apply that to your situation. Hopefully, you'll make it work. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As 'books_admin' user, try:

```
desc schema.books
```

If that works, try:

```
create [public] synonym books on schema.books;
desc books;
```

Comment: BTW, the '[public]' means it's optional.  Either do 'create synonym ...' or 'create public synonym....'.